# gnuplot add plots with different settings

Tags: settings, gnuplot, linestyle

I'd like to plot 3 functions in gnuplot while one of them has a higher sampling rate. The reason is that with that high sampling rate, dashed lines look somewhat compressed and become less distinguishable from each other.
The function with the high sampling rate should be plotted with a solid line, the other 2 with dashed lines. Here's a working example:

```
set term postscript dashed

set out 'test1.ps'

iu = {0.,1.}
kmax = 1.e1
lami = 1.e-2
lamf = 1.e2
lmax = lamf
tau = 5.

fun(x) = (exp(-2. * iu * x * pi * kmax) * (-1. + exp(2. * iu * x * pi * (1. + kmax)))**2 * (atan(lamf / (2. * x * pi)) - atan(lami / (2. * x * pi)))) / (2. * (-1. + exp(2. * iu * x * pi))**2 * x * pi * kmax**0 * (lamf - lami))

funSimp(x) = (2. * tau)/(4. * x**2 * pi**2 + tau**2)
funSimpler(x) = atan(lmax / (2. * x * pi)) / (2. * x * pi)

set xr [1e-4:500]
set yr [1e-6:10]

set logscale x
set logscale y

set samples 10000

plot \
fun(x) / 20.        t 'f'   w l, \
funSimp(x)          t 'fs'  w l, \
funSimpler(x) / 20. t 'fss' w l
```

The dashed lines of 'fs' and 'fss' look different from the ones displayed on the legend. I tried to do

```
set samples 10000

plot \
fun(x) / 20.        t 'f'   w l

set samples 50

plot \
funSimp(x)          t 'fs'  w l ls 2, \
funSimpler(x) / 20. t 'fss' w l ls 3
```

but this doesn't work out, as only the first plot gets printed to the file. `replot` also didn't help.

gnuplot 4.6.5, Win 7 64

Comment: A workaround perhaps! Why don't use `w l ls 4` instead of `w l ls 3` in the 3rd plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the postscript terminal. It uses relative coordinates when drawing the lines representing function. Since this may give rounding errors, a `moveto` is issued every 100 points. This interrupts the path, which becomes visible when using dash patterns. The patch in the sources is a one-liner.

As workaround I would suggest you to use the `pdfcairo` which doesn't have this problems. Then you can convert the pdf to eps if you need that as output format. Or you could use the `cairolatex eps` terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, just to add: I'm actually using gnuplottex (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gnuplottex). So based on your comment, I changed the terminal like that:

```
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex,terminaloptions={monochrome dashed dl 3.0 lw 1.0 rounded size 9cm,7cm}]
```

With this choice and the `epstopdf` package included beforehand, one can produce gnuplot figures directly with `pdfLaTeX` and even circumventing the problem with the dashes.

The only thing which I can't do at the moment is to crop the output, like one can do it with `dvips "xyz.dvi" -E`.

Comment: There is no need to use the `epstopdf` package since `cairolatex` also supports pdf output: `\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions={pdf monochrome ...}]`.